# android move screen it self to right when the moving image view inside it closes to right border

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, surfaceview, 2d-games

i really searched a lot and a lot for solving this issue for me .
is there is method using animation api or using canvas or surfaceview to move the main layout of screen it self from left to right when the moving image view inside the main layout closes to right border during its move from left to right or I must use any 2d game engine .
i want this of course to keep all views inside the main layout be visible always 
so i want to move the main layout it self as i mentioned .

i.e : something such as in all games that has a character moves to right and the screen moves also with it .

sorry if my question seems easy but this is i am new to game development in android and want to know if this is possible or not .
thanks inadvance

Comment: Post your relevant code, please

Comment: i didn't have certain code for this , i found this during my previous search 
http://obviam.net/index.php/moving-images-on-the-screen-with-androi/
but when the image has  a collision with the border it reverses its direction and i don't want this , i want to keep the image move from left to right with the ability to change its speed and when the image closes to right border of screen i want the screen moves also to right to keep the image view visible . i.e : something such as in all games that has a character moves to right and the screen moves also with it

Answer (score 0):

When you have stuff to draw that's bigger than your Canvas you can use `canvas.translate()` to move the canvas origin so your coordinates are all shifted.

I'm not a game developer, but if I were developing a game I would do something a little lower level than that.  I think that whatever your model is for your 2D game surface, you should also model the x,y,width&height of the screen so you have a "cliprect" or "viewport" into your game surface, then use those coordinates to determine what part of the game surface to draw and where to draw it.  Then if you have a game object and it's not within the current viewport, you don't waste any cycles trying to draw it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help , and now i decided to try with canvas.translate to see that the result